# When does a cubic equation has two roots with same absolute values

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, cubics

Let $$z^3+bz^2+cz+d=0$$ be a cubic equation with complex coefficients. Suppose $z_1, z_2$ and $z_3$ are its roots.
I need to find a condition on $b,c,d$ so that $$|z_1|=|z_2|.$$ How can I find such a relationship? Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: You could try reverse engineering: start with a factored cubic, and assuming two roots have the same modulus, see what happens when you multiply (note that complex conjugates have the same modulus, which certainly gives a *large class* of the cubics in question).

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted?

Comment: Earth to Nilan, come in please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|z_1| = |z_2|$, you can write $z_1 = u e^{i\theta}$ and $z_2 = u e^{-i\theta}$ for some real $\theta$ and complex $u$.  The cubic is then
$$(z - u e^{i\theta})(z - u e^{-i\theta})(z - z_3)= (z^2 - 2 u \cos(\theta) + u^2)(z - z_3)$$
We then get
$$ \eqalign{b &= -2 u \cos(\theta) - z_3\cr
            c &= 2 u z_3 \cos(\theta) +u^2\cr
            d &= -u^2 z_3\cr} $$

EDIT:
 We can eliminate the complex parameters $u$ and $z_3$ to obtain
an equation involving $b,c,d$ and $\cos(\theta)$:
$$ 64\,{d}^{2}  \cos^6 \left( \theta \right)  -16\,d
 \left( bc+3\,d \right)  \cos^4 \left( \theta \right)  + 4\, \left( {b}^{3}d-bcd+{c}^{3}+3\,{d}^{2} \right)   \cos^2
 \left( \theta \right)  -(bc - d)^2 = 0
$$
If we write $\cos^2(\theta) = v$, that is a cubic in $v$, and a condition (maybe the only one needed) on $b,c,d$ is that this cubic has a solution in the real interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2u\cos(\theta)z$?

Comment: You have only considered the case when $z_1$ is the conjugate of $z_2$. What about the case of repeated roots, i.e., $z_1 = z_2$

Comment: @Tanuj, that's $\theta=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what about $(z - i)^3$

Comment: @Tanuj, what about $(z-i)^3$? $u=i$, $\theta=0$, $z_3=i$. What's the problem?

Comment: If I may but note, you need not have $z_1$ and $z_2$ have opposite angles...

Comment: @GerryMyerson The problem is that you have defined it such that **a)** $b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, and **b)** $z_1=-z_2$, which is a direct result of your assumption that $z_1$ and $z_2$ have opposite $\theta$'s.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The problem is also that for for your example, $u\in\mathbb{C}$ to account for everything, and at that point, we may as well not care what $\theta$ is and have it equal $0$.  The purpose of $r$ in $re^{\theta\cdot i}$ is to represent the absolute value of the complex number.

Comment: @Simple, I'm trying to explicate Robert Israel's answer, for the benefit of Tanuj. Robert clearly states that $u$ is to be complex. The first sentence of Robert's answer is correct in all details and in all situations, and it allows him to get an answer to the original question, an answer OP may find useful (although OP hasn't had a lot to say...).

Comment: @GerryMyerson My bad, I'm sorry.  Its just that I usually don't see $re^{\theta i}$ with $r\in\mathbb{C}$ because the $\theta$ is supposed to take care of that part.  I have to ask though, it doesn't seem to be able to take care of the following situation:  $$(z-i)(z-1)(z-z_3)$$  What would $u$ and $\theta$ be?

Comment: @Simple, $u=(1+i)/\sqrt2$, $\theta=\pi/4$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wow, that is, odd....  But don't you think it is very difficult to find such $u$ or $\theta$ for the OP?

Comment: @Simple, I can't speak for OP, but we can take $u$ to be either one of the solutions to $u^2=z_1z_2$, and then get $\theta$ from $e^{i\theta}=z_1/u$. Or, we can first get $\theta$ from $z_1/z_2=e^{2i\theta}$, and then get $u$ from $u=z_2e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the conversation.  Nice and thought-provoking.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do have to ask, wouldn't it have been simpler with $u$ restricted to positive real numbers?

Comment: @Simple, simplicity is in the eye of the beholder. Robert liked his way, you like yours, and OP is missing in action.

Comment: @GerryMyerson LoL, I should quote that.  Minus the OP part though.

Answer (score 0):

In comparison to Robert Israel's answer, I note the following:

$$|ue^{\alpha\cdot i}|=u$$

for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u>0$.

Generally, Euler form of a complex number has the magnitude of the complex number as a coefficient and the real angle multiplied by $i$ with base $e$, which allows us to encompass all possible complex numbers with a slight exception of maybe $0+0i$.

Now, we can define our problem such that we have:

$$z_1=ue^{xi}, z_2=ue^{yi}$$

So now we have:

$$(z-ue^{xi})(z-ue^{yi})(z-z_3)$$

And you could multiply them all out if you want.

Another answer goes along the line of finding the root of a cubic polynomial, which may be found on [Wolfram|Alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ax%5E3%2Bbx%5E2%2Bcx%2Bd%3D0&lk=4)

Take the absolute value of the thing and try to solve using definitions of the absolute value operation:

$$|z|=|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Or:

$$|z|=z, z\ge0$$

$$|z|=-z,z\le0$$